# Symfony2: Best way for logging from anywhere

Tags: symfony, logging

I am working on my first Symfony project. I wonder what is the best / recommendet method to write log messages from anywhere in my code.

So far I used Monolog which works great when being used in a controller:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $logger->info('I just got the logger');
    $logger->error('An error occurred');

    // ...
}
```

But how can I use this code from any classe/code from my project? Doctrine entity classes for example cannot use `$this->get('logger')` to create the logger. How can I access the service in these classes? Or what other methode to log message is recommended in these cases?

EDIT: Of course I could create the logger in any controller and pass it down to all other classes. But this would be quite very cumbersome. There has to be a better way.

Comment: It's possible to access the logger service globally (search for the details) but you should really think about why you want to log from inside an entity and is it really necessary.  You could also use a Doctrine onLoad listener as well as a factory to insert the logger into entities.

Comment: I already searched for global usage of the logger but found only solutions that use the service container. Any hint? The entitiy classes are just an example for any NonContainerInheritedClass. I would like to use the logging for debugging.

Comment: $logger = $GLOBALS['kernel']->getContainer()->get('logger');  But since you are just starting out, maybe you should consider doing things the Symfony way.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, a first approach could be the creation of Event Listeners for specific actions in order to log only what you have decided to.

Have a look to this chapter : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

Hope it will help you.